# Host my own node.js webapp or deploy using a hosting service

Tags: node.js, express, deployment

I have a web app that's like a bulletin board where users upload their images and such. Is it best if I host this web app on my own hardware or use a hosting site?
The reason why I'm considering my own hardware is because it's my hardware which will be simple to me and something I know best, also I'll have file system access and see what the users are uploading, most hosting sites don't offer that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to base your choice depending on what's your favourite operating system for servers. If it's on window, I would recommend self hosting as most VPS with window cost way more than linux server. Overall, depending on the resources you need, the average cost of a linux server in the cloud is around 2.50 ~ 10.00 per months and with that you have a guaranteed fix IP address.

Soooo the question is, is all the trouble of setting up your server + maintaining it + managing a fixed IP with your ISP (plus ISP charges *) worth at worst 10 box per month? Your choice!

here is a few services you might want to consider for VPS

- https://aws.amazon.com/
- https://www.digitalocean.com/
- https://www.heroku.com/ (this one have free hosting if you don't mind the 24/7 uptime)

and there is so many others.

- As an example, my ISP charge around 100 CAD more per month just to consider my IP static and have a commercial profile for my internet.

Comment: You are right it. Although it would be much less tedious for me, by self hosting, it's much more expenisve. So these VPS' I can install imagemagick and make my own file folders in the server after deployment and save uploads in them and such? Btw I know heroku doesn't support that (so I've read) it deletes the files upon restart and what not.

Comment: on standard VPS yes, heroku is particular if you take the smaller dynamo (free) It's more like a temporary VPS. Amazon and Digital Ocean (which I use commonly) support whatever you want to do

Answer (score 1):

You can host on VPS. It can have any operation system you want. And you control it. It is much cheaper that dedicated hosting on your hardware.

http://www.google.com/search?q=vps

If you want to host node. You have to install manually, NodeJS, and the required NPM modules.